# Correct on input but panic on output in golang

Tags: go, panic

Trying to write a bit of go, I would like to create a sort of cat function in Golang:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "io/ioutil"
        "log"
)

func main() {
        // part to ask the question and get the input
        fmt.Print("Which file would you like to read?: ")
        var input string
        fmt.Scanln(&input)
        fmt.Print(input)

        // part to give the output
        f, err := os.Open(os.Args[1]) // Open the file                                       
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln("my program broken")
        }

        defer f.Close() // Always close things open                                          

        bs, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln("my program broken")
        }

        // part to print the output
        fmt.Printf("input", bs) // %s convert directly in string the result                  

}
```

But I get a go panic on execution and do not find more explicit information.

What I have done wrong?

How can I get more information about that error from the terminal?

> $
>    go run gocat.go Which file would you like to read?: gocat.go
>   gocat.gopanic: runtime error: index out of range
>
> goroutine 1 [running]: panic(0x4b1840, 0xc42000a0e0)
>   /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1 main.main()
>   /home/user/git/go-experimentations/gocat/gocat.go:23 +0x4ba exit
>   status 2

Comment: `os.Args` holds what was passed to your program on its command line. You're supposedly intend to open a file which name was interactively input by the user and ended up in the variable named "input". Why the heck don't you attempt to use it as the name of the file to input?

Comment: to request the user

Comment: Uh.... what? I cannot make sense of this.

Comment: oh sorry, i have just understand what you mean -_-'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `=` rather than `:=`
So here is from where your error comes from.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine you found some examples online and don't quite understand what is going on.

From the [`os`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/) package's documentation.

> Args hold the command-line arguments, starting with the program name.

Since you started your program without any arguments and `os.Args` is a slice, the program panics when you access out of the slice's bounds. (Like trying to access an element of any array that does not exist)

It looks like you are trying to prompt for the input here

```
var input string
fmt.Scanln(&input)
fmt.Print(input)
```

All you need to do is replace

```
f, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
```

With:

```
f, err := os.Open(input)
```

Your last print statement is also incorrect.

It should be:

```
// part to print the output
fmt.Printf("input \n %s", string(bs))
```

You need to cast `bs` which is currently `[]byte` to a `string` and you need to add `%s` to indicate to `fmt.Printf` where `string(bs)` should be placed in the format string

Comment: the output produce the input + the output but i need just the output (that if i give the full directories information, but I wish to use ~/ for user and that give back that the program is broken

Comment: Removing the input will be easy just remove it from the `Printf` statement. `fmt.Printf("%s", string(bs))` using the `~` short cut will add a little bit of programming. You could check if the first character is a `~` and if it is get the `$HOME` env variable using [`os.Getenv`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv) then construct your path with  `$HOME`

Comment: nop that produce an error on ~/bob and an input+output on output on /home/user/bob

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. What was the error? Is `/home/user/bob` a file that can be read?

Comment: cat ~/bob read just fine but not go run gocat.go then after the request ~/bob

Answer (score 1):

not `os.Open(os.Args[1])`, `Args[1]` is out of range. you should open the file you input like this:

```
f, err := os.Open(input)
```

Comment: with that on the request I got:

Comment: go run gocat2.go Which file would you like to read?: ~/bob ~/bobpanic: runtime error: index out of range gorountine 1 [running]: panic(0x4...) /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a main.main() /home/user/git/go/gocat2/gocat2.go:22 +0x4ba exist status 2

Comment: sounds better but the output is not just fine .. now get: go run gocat2.go Which file would you like to read?: ~/bob ~/bob2016/12/27 16:23.10 my program broken exit status 1

Comment: and if i specify the /home/user/ it produce an output like: /home/user/bobinput%!(EXTRA []uint8=[104 109 109 32 104 109 109 10])

Comment: @aurelien just input the file name, and use `fmt.Printf("input %s", bs)` to print the text file.

Comment: this produce: ~/bob2016/12/27 16:38:08 my program broken exit status 1

Comment: and with the /home/user/bob with just %s and/or with input %s it produce an output with not just the response but the input and the output

Comment: That was that + the point that there is a line too much with a print output of the input on fmt.Print(input) that should not be and produce the + input line on output